# Solving a quadratic vector equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm interested in the vector equation
$$
a-Bx-2Cx-\left[\begin{array}{c}
x'C^{-1}A_{1}C^{-1}x\\
\vdots\\
x'C^{-1}A_{n}C^{-1}x
\end{array}\right]=0
$$
where $x$ is an unknown $n\times 1$ column vector, and the square and symmetric matrices $A_i$, $B$ and $C$ are positive definite. $a$ is also an $n\times 1$ column vector.

Is there any hope of solving for $x$?

**What I have tried so far**

Let $d_i=x'C^{-1}A_{i}C^{-1}x$, then we can write that system as
$$
a-Bx-2Cx-d=0
$$
and its solution is
$$
x=\left(B+2C\right)^{-1}\left(a-d\right).
$$
From there we can go back to $d$ and find
$$
d_{i}=\left(a-d\right)'\left(B+2C\right)^{-1}C^{-1}A_{i}C^{-1}\left(B+2C\right)^{-1}\left(a-d\right).
$$
But then we have another quadratic system in $d$ to solve, which does not seem much easier.

Are there well-know solutions for systems of the form
$$
d_{i}=\left(a-d\right)'E_{i}\left(a-d\right)
$$
for all $i$?

Comment: Two quick thoughts on this: you can obviously simplify things a bit by combining matrices $B$ and $C$. But what you've written is pretty much the most general system of simultaneous quadratics possible (positive definiteness aside). You'll be getting $2^n$ roots - you may want to look at numerical methods.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? If you've a particular (small) example system you can share it might be useful just to test out and compare different approaches

Comment: @ChrisLewis No, I didn't get anywhere. In one dimension we can solve the last equation using the usual formula for the roots of a second-order polynomial. But I don't know how to tackle this problem in general.

Comment: It's a huge jump to go from one dimension to the general case. $3$ dimensions is probably where it starts to get interesting. Could you post a $3D$ example as part of the question for something to work on?